# how to change x-axis labels in plot.ts

Tags: r, date, timeserieschart

I have the data set with daily dates (5-days trading in a week) and price data. I want to change the x axis labels to the plot. I am using ts.plot function to plot my data. My data spans from 2020-01-27 to 2021-07-30. I want to change it to D-M-Y first. Then I want to show all the dates with a one week gap in my x-axis label.
The following code I am using:

```
pricet <- ts(price, start = c(2020, 27), frequency = 260) 
# I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly or not. Shall I include end also.
plot.ts(pricet)
```

Please give me suggestion.
[image]. I want to format the x axis labels with one week gap.

```
pricet <- ts(price, start = c(2020, 27), frequency = 260)
plot.ts(pricet)
```

Comment: You want 80 labels along the x axis?

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.